# Prevent UISplitViewController from closing the primary tab on a click in the detail view?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uisplitviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

Using a `UISplitViewController` for an iPad app where the display mode is `PrimaryOverlay`, with `UITableViewControllers` embedded in `UINavigationControllers` in both views.

When the primary viewController is reloading content and showing a `UIRefreshControl`, I'd like to prevent a tap outside of the primary view to cause the primary to close. I poked around looking for some `UIGestureRecognizer`that might be intercepting the tap, but cannot find one in any of what would appear to be the relevant views. Nor can I seem to prevent this by adding my own screen sized view over either of the two split panes, or even if added as a subview of the splitView itself.

The split view controller does install two gesture recognizers in the primary tableview, probably related to the swipe gesture, one a tap and one a swipe recognizer. But disabling both (by setting their `enabled`  property to false) has no effect on the behavior, as does removing them totally.

There is no obvious delegate method that can be used to stop the close either. At this point I'm at a total loss on what might be done to get the behavior I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm only able to prevent the primary view controller from closing using the following code:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, 
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
            window?.userInteractionEnabled = false

            return true
    }
}
```

But this obviously has other bad side effects (the user won't be able to interact with your app at all).

Perhaps a better solution is allow the user to close the primary view controller, and have your primary view controller handle this appropriately. This seems to be how Apple intended the `UISplitViewController` to be used in this display mode.

What is the motivation to keep the primary view controller open while refreshing?

Comment: There would be a refresh of data going on - its modal - and if the user can close that pane they can start interacting with the app. Now, I can block all interaction, but its messy. If I cannot find a good solution I just won't support refresh in the primary pane. Interesting that the window is the culprit - I was thinking the same thing - I went poking around looking for gesture recognizers in the window's gesture recognizers but didn't find any. Hmmm - it might be possible to disable that interaction for the period of the refresh. Let me try that out...

Comment: Would it be possible to present the view controller modally, rather than setting it as the primary view controller of your split view controller?

Comment: No, its a "master" controller and always in that primary position. I can always re-architect app, but disabling refresh in this view is the easiest solution. BTW, your solution works but look at the console - tons of error messages! I tried turning user interaction off for the split view itself, then its master and primary viewController's views - nothing. So obviously split view is hooking into the window itself. That's not going to be easy (or advisable) to work around.

Comment: Yeah there were a bunch of messages in the console. I agree that removing the refresh control is probably the best way to go.

Comment: I'm going to award you the answer as technically it does work, and it prevented me wasting more time on trying to find a solution. However, I did find a work around, will add that as my own answer, you can read it shortly (but don't read it on a full stomach :-))

Answer (score 0):

I did find a work-around here - a way to prevent the pane from closing while some long running task is progressing - but while not elegant it appears its workable.

Work-around: pop an Alert, and add text fields that can be used to display progress of the activity (I know, yikes!)

I just verified that the Alert blocks touches outside the view's boundary. So you create an alert, you add one or two text fields, and get references in them before the alert is shown.

As your refresh control spins (or perhaps you close it first), you periodically update one of the text fields with progress information (I haven't verified this works yet, will update answer when I find out).

If you want it to look nicer than just plain text, use an NSAttributed string with an image. The image can be a progress like bar! However, updating it may cause screen flashes (again, have not done this).

Alternately, the Alert just shows a Cancel button, and the user can see through the background some progress information.

Yeah, real hack. Perhaps the alternate solution isn't all that bad, if the progress control in the background is viewable. Note that a refresh control accepts attributed text, so the progress indicator could be implemented there using it.